# UIScrollView child view from Storyboard. Why extra 20 pixels top and left?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view divided into four sections. A corner view in the top left (unused, invisible); a horizontal view across the top (`timelineAreaView` in the code) displaying one set of axis labels; a vertical view on the left side displaying another set of axis labels, and the rest of the view is a large collection view. It's not unlike a spreadsheet.

The problem is that I am trying to use a UIScrollView in the top view. If I add a test UIView to the top everything is fine. Here's the code:

```
    let timelineViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TimelineViewController") as? TimelineViewController
    addChildViewController(timelineViewController!)
    timelineAreaView.addSubview(timelineViewController!.view)
    timelineViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    timelineViewController!.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    timelineAreaView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: timelineViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: timelineAreaView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    timelineAreaView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: timelineViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: timelineAreaView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    timelineAreaView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: timelineViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: timelineAreaView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
    timelineAreaView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: timelineViewController!.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: timelineAreaView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
```

TimelineViewController is a plain UIViewController with the UIView property backgroundColor set to blue.

Here's the result, displayed in that excellent tool [Reveal](http://revealapp.com):
[image: correct layout]

So far so good. But it needs to have a UIScrollView. So If I add a UIScrollView to that UIViewController in the storyboard it looks like this:

[image: scrollview added in storyboard]

Its constraints now look like this:

[image: constraints]

Here's the problem shown in Reveal - the UIScrollView is highlighted:

[image]

Reveal Layout Inspector shows:

[image: 20 pixels added]

So WHY are there 20 pixels added to the y origin and subtracted from the x origin in the frame?

My first thought was to look at the view controllers settings for "Adjust Scroll View Insets" and "Under Top Bars" but these have no effect. I cannot find any setting that has any effect here.

Going back to the storyboard and compensating for the two mysterious 20 pixel errors, i.e. [image: ugly hack]

This makes it look just like I want. But I shouldn't have to do this. What's going on?

Comment: do you want the scroll view to be under the status bar? little fuzzy here, can't understand what you see on a device/simulator.

Comment: Yes - the problem picture captured in Reveal shows the frame of the scrollview is below and to the left of the view it should be in. The final view is from the top of the screen, underlapping the status bar.

Comment: Top Layout Guide should be under status bar. If you want to overlap the status bar, make a constraint to the view, not the Top Layout Guide.

Comment: regarding horizontal shifts - you have constraints pinned to margins - there is a shift in this situation. pin leading and trailing to the view, with margins disabled.